# kubectl: get cut pod name

Tags: bash, kubectl, minikube

Im playing with "`kubectl get pods...`", and there is use case:

I have some pods returning(lets leave only names):

```
$ kubectl get pods | cut -d' ' -f1

admin-fe-124
admin-be-12345
some-Other-Staff-123
```

Question: is it possible to filter out (with `kubectl get pods`) only first eg 2 words(3...4...as i wish) of the name?
I want to see following:

```
$ kubectl get pods... (some magic)

admin-be
admin-fe
some-Other
```

So, what should be there under "some magic"? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean print just the first column e.g. Names?

```
kubectl get po | awk '{print $1}'
NAME
kubeserve-68776dd94c-2wmc9
kubeserve-68776dd94c-qvg6c
kubeserve-68776dd94c-vqbcf
myreplicaset-gd6hj
myreplicaset-mfthn
myreplicaset-nsb9s
nginx-7db9fccd9b-hrp57
nginx-7db9fccd9b-m6t6l
ssd-monitor-lgmmr
ssd-monitor-m5sz6
```

You can then use

`awk '{print $1, $2}'` etc.

edit: or do you mean print the first two entries?

In which case just pipe the output to set and skip the first line e.g.

```
kubectl get po | awk '{print $1}' | sed -n 2,3p
kubeserve-68776dd94c-2wmc9
kubeserve-68776dd94c-qvg6c
```

Comment: @Dmitry how did you resolve your problem because it doesn't gave you what you wanted ?

Answer (score 3):

Using array and variable substitution

```
# test function to create needed output
test_names () {
    echo "
        admin-fe-124
        admin-be-12345
        some-Other-Staff-123
    "
}

test=( $(test_names) ) # create an array
echo "${test[@]%-*}"   # use variable substitution to cut last part
```

In your case

```
names=( $(kubectl get pods | cut -d' ' -f1) )
echo "${names[@]%-*}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way

```
kubectl get pods | awk -F '-' {'print $1"-"$2'}
```

where '-' is like a separator and $1,$2 ... are words

Comment: This will print incorrect names like this: 'admin fe'